# Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported using TransactionScope in asp.net core 2 app

Tags: ado.net, asp.net-core-2.0

When opening sql connection inside TransactionScope its giving "Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported" error. I am using ado.net in asp.net core 2 app.

```
        using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                repository.Insert(entity);                    
                ts.Complete();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ts.Dispose();
            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

If you encounter this problem when using .Net Standard, you can add a recent reference to System.Data.SqlClient and this problem will go away.

Comment: Confirmed, I'm using .Net Core 2.2, and installing the latest NuGet package System.Data.SqlClient (4.8.0 at time of writing) in the project with the SQL access code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.All with the individual package references, and then add a PackageReference to "System.Data.SqlClient", Version="4.3.1".

Here is the link to the solution (for reference) that worked for me ([Dapper is throwing System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection exception after upgrading System.Data.SqlClient to version 4.5.0-preview2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421371/dapper-is-throwing-system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection-exception-after-upgrading/48273860#48273860)).

This worked for System.Data.SqlClient Version up to 4.3.1., 4.4.0 and above gives the same error.